# How does geo targeting affect SEO if I set it or leave it unchecked in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, geolocation, geotargeting

I have a tech blog which is aiming to get a global audience just like the gsmarena (popular tech blog) does.

Do I need to set any specific geolocation or leave it unchecked?  I don't want to rank my site to any specific location.

Comment: Leave it unchecked then. I'm not sure how much an influence that setting has now. In the past it seemed to just give a slight boost for the selected country, and no noticeable effect internationally.

Comment: Thanks. It would really help me.